# What is the word for the face of a mountain or a huge rock that rhymes with edifice?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think it kind of rhymes with *'edifice'* or *'*Irifice*' or something.

Can someone give me a word for the face of a mountainous brown rock?

Comment: Thanks @jimm101 If you don't mind, may I ask you why shouldn't we change the title. I thought it would be better removed and added in body.

Comment: It's more in line with the author's original intent, and clarifies the question. The question isn't for any word, but a rhyming one.

Comment: @jimm101 OK. Got it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 15):

A [***precipice***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precipice): a very steep side of a mountain or cliff (*Merriam-Webster*)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Cornice** a mass of snow, ice, rock projecting over a mountain ridge, cliff or corrie.

[image: Blockquote]